# Custom changes performed on WP + WooCom site on maintenance subdomain. How to perform a migration to a main domain?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, content, migration

I was working on a WP + WooCommerce website (shop + blog), very active site - a lot of orders, users and posts. I was working with some plugins (settings), installing new plugins, removing old ones and even did some custom coding.

All the changes were performed on a "cloned" website, migrated to a maintenance subdomain. Now the changes are done. What is the best way to migrate the site to its main domain, without losing anything? Because in the meantime plenty of new articles and orders were posted, also a lot of users registered, etc. I need the posts and orders to remain the same (IDs and everything), but I want my changes to apply.

Basically, everything related to code and WP settings needs to be overwritten by my changes, and everything posted to the site (it's content) needs to be the same.

Comment: any attempt in research at all? Can't remember how many times I answered this question by now :( the tldr is that your work flow is wrong if you feel like you need to sync DB between dev and production

Comment: Absolutely. I acutally spend a day trying different methods. I tried to manaully migrate files on FTP server, overwriting only the edited ones. Then migrating the database and keeping the existing tables. I tried to migrate everything except wp_posts and wp_postmeta. I tried plenty of migrating plugins. Every method I tried produced some errors. I am actually glad to hear my workflow is wrong, because I really need to learn a proper way to do this. Do you have some link to a question in which you posted your answer? Thank you.

Comment: do you use GIT?

Comment: Sadly I do not. I really have zero knowledge on Git.

Comment: so I think regardless of wordpress and workflows this is the thing you should learn first. Not have the ability to be able to compare code from today with code from 30 days ago is just bad, and even if you do daily manual backups you are not likely to keep reasons for changes in them. It is not like GIT is simple, but for simple usages there is so many UI tools, web based and not, and so much documentation it is just the "go to" tool for keeping track of code changes. Then once you have GIT and can deploy from it with "pull" something which is much less dangarous than uploading files via FTP